# Can we use "ransom" for things not for people, for example, "he stole an antique for ransom"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In the dictionary,

> [ransom](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ransom_1?q=ransom): money that is paid to somebody so that they will set free a
> person who is being kept as a prisoner by them

It seems like "**ransom**" is for people, for example, "**They kidnapped the kid for ransom**".

Now, a man stole a "**17th century vase**" but he didn't want to sell it but called the owner of the vase and asked for a ransom.

Is it correct to say "**he stole an antique for ransom**"?

Comment: The definition you link to includes an example referring to cattle; most online dictionaries say 'someone _or something_'.

Comment: Erm... [***ransomeware***,](https://www.malwarebytes.com/ransomware) anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *wrong* to say "stole (something) for ransom" but [a much more common phrasing is to say that it was stolen, and **held** for ransom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stolen+for+ransom%2Cheld+for+ransom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3); *held* is by far the most common collocation with *ransom*, so anything else sounds unusual.

*Ransom* is usually applied to humans, but not always:
[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ransom) says

> a sum of money demanded in exchange for someone **or something** that has been taken

*Ransom* is so normally applied only to people that anything else sounds strange; Ngrams doesn't even list "it" as a common object of [*was held for ransom*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+was+held+for+ransom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) or [*was ransomed*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+was+ransomed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

But you can find it being used for other objects:

> [Bounce house company owner says thieves stole equipment, holding it for ransom](https://news.yahoo.com/bounce-house-company-owner-says-045216151.html)

> [A Kent County, Mich., woman said her treasured Jesus statue has been returned after it was held for ransom over doggie doo.](https://www.upi.com/Odd_News/2008/01/21/Jesus-statue-held-for-ransom-over-dog-poop/90161200948470/)

In conclusion: Yes, you can use *ransom* with objects, but the more common phrasing is "held for ransom", not "stolen for ransom".